# How to create a column containing a JSON that has names defined from the value of a column in another table?

Tags: sql, json, teradata

I have a source table with data in VARCHAR format like the example below.
I want to insert the data in another table in a JSON format (the result column itself can be of JSON or VARCHAR type).

- For each Id, there is at least 1 JSONName/JSONValue pair.
- But each Id doesn't have the same kinds and number of JSONName/JSONValue pairs.
- Each Id can have maximum 50 JSONName/JSONValue pairs.
- The order of the pairs in the value of the ResultJSON column doesn't matter.

---

```
SourceTable:
____________________________
| Id | JSONName | JSONValue |
|____|__________|___________|
| 1  | Name     | John      |
| 2  | Name     | Henry     |
| 2  | Age      | 32        |
| 3  | Age      | 56        |
| 3  | Location | US        |
| 4  | Age      | 24        |
| 4  | Name     | Andrew    |
| 4  | Location |           |
```

What I want:

```
Expected ResultTable:
____________________________________________________
| Id |               ResultJSON                     |
|____|______________________________________________|
| 1  | {"Name":"John"}                              |
| 2  | {"Name":"Henry","Age":"32"}                  |
| 3  | {"Age":"56", "Location":"US"}                |
| 4  | {"Age":"24","Name":"Andrew","Location":null} |
```

What I get with my current query:

```
Wrong resultTable:
_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
| Id |               ResultJSON                                                                                                |
|____|_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________|
| 1  | [{"JSONName":"Name","JSONValue":"John"}]                                                                                |
| 2  | [{"JSONName":"Name","JSONValue":"Henry"},{"JSONName":"Age","JSONValue":"32"}]                                           |
| 3  | [{"JSONName":"Age","JSONValue":"56"},{"JSONName":"Location","JSONValue":"US"}]                                          |
| 4  | [{"JSONName":"Age","JSONValue":"24"},{"JSONName":"Name","JSONValue":"Andrew"},{"JSONName":"Location","JSONValue":null}] |
```

Current query:

```
INSERT INTO ResultTable
(
     Id
    ,ResultJSON
)
SELECT
     SourceTable.Id
    ,JSON_AGG(SourceTable.JSONName,SourceTable.JSONValue)
FROM SourceTable
INNER JOIN OtherTable ON SourceTable.Id=OtherTable.Id
```

Is it possible to do it with Teradata JSON functions? If not, what would be the most optimized query to do it?

Comment: You can remove the unneeded parts using REGEXP_REPLACE, but that's probably not the most optimized version. What the defined length of the JSONName/JSONValue columns, how big is the source table and how often do you need to run this?

Comment: JSONName is a VARCHAR(64) and JSONValue a VARCHAR(150). JSONName contain only words like 'Name' or 'Address', but JSONValue can contain any kinds of characters. The source table is expected to contain a few millions lines and we need to run this on a daily basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the unwanted parts using a RegEx:

```
SELECT
   SourceTable.Id
  ,RegExp_Replace(Cast(Json_Agg(SourceTable.JSONName AS "#A",SourceTable.JSONValue AS "#B") AS VARCHAR(32000)), '"#A":|,"#B"|^\[|\]$|}(?=,{")|(?<="},){')
FROM SourceTable
GROUP BY 1
```

The RegEx removes all of the follwing:

- `"#A":`
- `,"#B"`
- a leading `[`
- a trailing `]`
- `}` if it's followed by `,{"`
- `{` if it's following `"},`

Edit:

Based on the comments this RegEx leaves superfluous opening braces. This seems to work better:

```
'"#A":|,"#B"|^[|]$|}(?=,)|(?<=,){'
```

Comment: I adapted the regex to my purposes, the one you posted leaves superfluous opening braces in the result: '"#A":|,"#B"|^\[|\]$|}(?=,)|(?<=,){'
I'll get back to you later after the comparison in efficiency between the different queries :)

Comment: Yep, this is definitely more efficient :) Can you edit your answer with the regex in the comment above?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query I got in the end:

```
INSERT INTO DB.RESULT_TABLE
(
     ResultId
    ,ResultJSON
)
WITH RECURSIVE MergedTable (Id, mergedList, rnk)
AS
(
    SELECT
         Id
        ,TRIM('"' || JSONName ||'":'|| COALESCE('"' || JSONValue || '"','null')) AS mergedList
        ,rnk
    FROM DB.SOURCE_TABLE
    WHERE rnk = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
         SourceTable.Id
        ,MergedTable.mergedList || ',' || TRIM('"' || SourceTable.JSONName ||'":' || COALESCE('"' || SourceTable.JSONValue || '"','null')) AS mergedList
        ,SourceTable.rnk
    FROM DB.SOURCE_TABLE SourceTable
    INNER JOIN MergedTable MergedTable
        ON MergedTable.rnk + 1 = SourceTable.rnk
        AND  SourceTable.Id = MergedTable.Id
)
SELECT
     MergedTable.Id                       AS ResultId
    ,'{' || MergedTable.mergedList || '}' AS ResultJSON
FROM MergedTable
QUALIFY RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ResultId ORDER BY rnk DESC) = 1
;
```

Comment: Some remarks: #1. Recursion is not very efficient (might need a large spool for all the intermediate rows). #2. The datatype of a column is determined by the base Select, in your case it will be something like `VarChar(220)` for `mergedList` and the data in the UNION ALL might be truncated. #3. You probably calculated the `rnk` in a previous step, adding more overhead. I posted a query utilizing RegExp_Replace, can you report which is more efficient?

Comment: When testing, I got no problem of truncated data with the UNION ALL. Does it happen under specific conditions?

Comment: The first Select determines the datatype, in your case it's the resulting type of `'"' || JSONName ||'":'|| COALESCE('"' || JSONValue || '"'`. If the length of the concatenated is greater than that it's silently truncated. It's usually better to specify a maximum length using a `CAST AS VARCHAR(...)`